# How to refer to the controls of a multi project solution from a module function

Tags: vb.net

I have managed to combine 2 projects in one solution.
Project1 is the startup project.

**Project1/Button1** opens **Form1 of Project2** with the code below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim frm1ofProject2 As New Project2.Form1
    frm1ofProject2.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

I have a **ComboBox1** control on **Form1 of Project2** and I get the selectedindex number of the Combobox with the following code:

```
Public Function BKS_IMP_Bul()

    Dim secilen As Integer
    secilen = Form1.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex

End Function
```

The code above is in a **function defined in Module1 of Project2** and it does not work as I expect. It returns a value of ***secilen=-1*** whatever I select from the ComboBox. If I move the code into a button click and change the code to;

> secilen = Form1.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex

it works, however it needs to be in that module. I do not know what I am missing so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The variable `Form1` must be a reference to the same open form containing the ComboBox. If you create a new `Form1` in the other project, then it will have another copy of the ComboBox having another SelectedIndex.

Comment: When you use `Form1.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex` you are accessing the DEFAULT INSTANCE of Form1. This is not the same instance as the instance of Form1 on screen created with `New`.  Go do some research on how default instances work in VB.Net.